# My XML output with date Format using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have my xml File

```
   <root>
         <item>Apple</item>
         <name><![CDATA[Indhu && Mathi]]></name>
         <date>28-02-2018</date>
         <dollar>500</dollar>
   </root>
```

Have my XSL file as:

```
      <xsl:import href="lookupValues.xsl"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
         <html>
           <head></head>
           <body>
           <h1>Hello World</h1>
           <table border="1">
           <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="root/item"/></td> </tr>
           <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="root/name"/></td> </tr>
           <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="root/date"/></td></tr>


          <tr>
           <td> Date Format </td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="format_date">
                <xsl:with-param name="arg" select="root/date" />
          </xsl:call-template> </td>
         </tr>       
           </table>
         </body>
         </html>
          </xsl:template>
```

Also the call function is written as 
   lookupValues.xsl:

```
     <xsl:template name="format_date">
    <xsl:param name="arg"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDay" select="substring-before($arg, '/')"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="vMonth" select="substring-before(substring-after($arg, '/'), '/')"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="vYear" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($arg, '/'), '/'), ' ')"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($vDay) &lt; 3">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vDay"/>      
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($vMonth) &lt; 4">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vMonth"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="$vYear"/>     
</xsl:template>
```

I want to print my date  in DD/MMM/YYYY format as . Need some corrections in my code. Am not sure about the function.

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? `1.0` or `2.0`?

Comment: I am using Version 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 does not provide any inbuilt functions for date formatting. There are [date time extensions](http://exslt.org/date/index.html) for slightly easing the task of working with dates, however not all the extensions work as per our requirements.

You will have to write custom templates for handling the conversion of numeric month to month name i.e. `02` to `Feb`. Below is the stylesheet that will convert the date from `DD-MM-YYYY` format to `DD/MMM/YYYY` format.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <formattedDate>
            <xsl:call-template name="format-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="date" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </formattedDate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="format-date">
        <xsl:param name="date" />
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 1, 2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 4, 2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 7, 4)" />
        <xsl:variable name="monthName">
            <xsl:call-template name="month-name">
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($day, '/', $monthName, '/', $year)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="month-name">
        <xsl:param name="month" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 1">Jan</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 2">Feb</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 3">Mar</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 4">Apr</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 5">May</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 6">Jun</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 7">Jul</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 8">Aug</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 9">Sep</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 10">Oct</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 11">Nov</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 12">Dec</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: instead of if we can go for 'choose/when' while choosing this option we can get two things: 1) Performance will be fast and 2) if some new value will come then we can handle in otherwise section.

Answer (score 1):

If your input format of dates is permanent and looks like 28-02-2018 (dd-mm-yyyy), then capturing of the date from the param can be simplified:

```
<xsl:template name="format_date">
    <xsl:param name="arg"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($arg,1,2)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="month">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($arg,4,2)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="year">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($arg,7,4)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="monthName">
        <xsl:call-template name="month-name">
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($day, '/', $monthName, '/', $year)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yeah! I got it. Performance wise it is better. Thank you so much

Comment: True. I overlooked that aspect. Updated the answer to include this change.